# Is there Hurdle model function for GAMM on R?

Tags: r, function, statistics, package, statistical-test

I am working with a dataset that is **zero inflated** and I found a function that allows me to do a GLMM with the **glmmadmb** function. But, I realized that my data are not linearly related with the environmental variables I want to test, this is why I am looking for a GAMM instead of a GLMM.

Does anyone know which function can replace **glmmadmb** for a **GAMM** ?

Comment: I would suggest to give a look to the `gamlss` package (see here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gamlss.dist/gamlss.dist.pdf)

Comment: If the suggestion was useful to solve your problem, you might think to post an answer for people with the same issues.